# Redirecting cancel button to url

Tags: php, html

I have the following code which is causing me problem. The code generates two buttons, one to remove the selected project and the other to cancel the deletion of the project. The remove function works well, however I haven't found a way to make my cancel button redirect to my url (when I click on it, nothing happens). Any clue?

```html
...
 echo "<form method='post'>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$currentid."' name='project'/>";
  echo "<b>".$project_name."</b>";
?>
 <div class="btn_2"> <input type="submit" name="save" value="Remove"><input type="submit" onclick="window.location.replace('www.myurl.ca')" value="Cancel"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a submit button and tagging JS on to it.  I'm expecting that you're actually submitting the form, but I could be wrong.

If nothing is happening with your JS, you may try doing `window.location.href = "www.myurl.ca"; return false;` where including the return false should avoid the submit.

The best solution would probably be to make it a plain button and wrap it in an A tag.  You would avoid submitting your form, redirect, and all without requiring JS be active.

```html
...
 echo "<form method='post'>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$currentid."' name='project'/>";
  echo "<b>".$project_name."</b>";
?>
 <div class="btn_2"> <input type="submit" name="save" value="Remove"><a href="http://www.myurl.ca"><button type="button">Cancel</button></a></div>
</form>
```

Comment: It worked. My only little problem is that the new button is 1 or 2 pixel lower than my first submit button. Any idea to have it aligned? Thanks

Comment: @Guillaume That would depend on the CSS you have most likely.  By default, both a input type submit and button type button should be a plain button.  If you would like to provide me with a link to where you're displaying this, I could look.

Without viewing it, I would suggest looking at the A tag in your browser's developer tools.  It's probably using some padding, which you can overwrite with `style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"` as a tag attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Using the formaction button attribute works.

`<input type="submit" name="save" value="Cancel" formaction="http://www.myurl.ca">`